# Angular 4 components are not routing correctly when deployed

Tags: angular, npm, router, angular-routing

I used NPM Modules to load my Angular 4 App, it runs default on localhost: 4200

I used Routing feature to navigate my components in My app, before the deployment of my application it works fine but after deploying the Application it runs Page Not found Error, this type of error shows only when I refresh the page.
[When I reload the page it was shown like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKnR7.png)

Comment: where should you route to? `dist` folder??

Comment: Did you try `<a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>` in `app.component.html`

Comment: You need to configure the **server** to serve index.html for all the URLs used in the routes of the application. Or switch back to hash-based location strategy.

Comment: Yes, I tried `<a>` tag but it doesn't work @ShanilFernando

Comment: Can you give some more detail @JBNizet because I'm new to Angular

Comment: @SuriyaReddy not `<a>`. see the` /` before `contact`.

Comment: That doesn't have much to do with Angular. It depends on what you're using on the **server**. When your browser address bar contains /foo/bar, and you refresh, the browser sends a GET request to your server, for the path /foo/bar. So your server must respond with the index.html page, so that the angular application loads, starts, detect that the path is /foo/bar, and thus display the component for that route.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding `providers: [

    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],` in app.module.ts file. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding

```
providers: [ {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} ]
```

in app.module.ts

Thank you to the persons who tried to solve my issue :)